# Setting Custom Headers for Assets in Rails on Heroku Cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a cedar application that uses Rails 4.0 and the asset pipeline. I'd like to set custom headers for all assets from the asset pipeline. How can this be done?

Comment: Which kind of header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way would be to use a rack plugin, something like this:

```
class RackAssetFilter
   def initialize app
      @app = app
   end

   def call env
      @status, @headers, @body = @app.call env
      if env['PATH_INFO'].starts_with?( "/assets/" )
         @headers['X-Header-1'] = 'value'
         # ... 
      end
      return [@status, @headers, @body]
   end
end
```

To enable it, in application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before( ActionDispatch::Static, RackAssetFilter )
```

Keep in mind you need to declare or load the RackAssetFilter via require before you insert it into the middleware stack in application.rb

Answer (score 2):

Since Rails 5 you can use the config `public_file_server.headers` in the configuration file of the corresponding environment that you want to apply the desired headers, for example:

```rb
    # in config/environments/production.rb
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
     "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=31536000"
    }
```

The above snippet will configure the `Cache-Control` header with `public, max-age=31536000` value for you assets in the production environment. You can also set any custom headers.